# Order column using calculation and class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an app that allows users to post. Those posts can be upvoted and downvoted. Each post record keeps track of `upvotes:integer` and `downvotes:integer`. I want to be able to order the records by which has the most upvotes total (in other words: `upvotes-downvotes`). I have absolutely no idea how to do this because I do not quite understand how Class methods interact with the object they are called on. This is my attempt:

My controller:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.find(:all).most_votes.order(vote_difference)
end
```

My Post.rb Model:

```
def self.most_votes
   vote_difference = (upvotes-downvotes)
end
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can actually insert the calculation right into the .order() value:

```
@posts = Post.find(:all).order('upvotes + downvotes')
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the `find(:all)` for this to work or else the collection will be converted into an array before `order` is called, throwing an error.